# Django admin how to order by model property?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model with property and I want to be able to sort instances in the admin panel by that property.

My model with `_points` property:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    inviter = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def _points(self):
        res = CustomUser.objects.filter(inviter_id=self.id).count()
        return res
```

My admin:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['inviter', '_points']
 

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
```

the `_points` field is displayed in the admin panel, but I cannot sort entries by it

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to order a queryset by a property. You can only order it by database fields